Running anchor build gives error in solana program
Upon running
anchor build

[2024-12-03T12:07:16.596224000Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to install platform-tools: HTTP status client error (404 Not Found) for url (https://github.com/anza-xyz/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.42/platform-tools-osx-x86_64.tar.bz2)
My specifications:
Apple M1 OS15.1.1
rustc --version
rustc 1.83.0 (90b35a623 2024-11-26)

solana --version
solana-cli 2.0.18 (src:f77014dc; feat:607245837, client:Agave)

anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.30.1



when i downgraded solana cli version to 1.18.0 this error is gone but getting new error
= note: ld: library 'System' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: could not compile typenum (build script) due to previous error

At first, you need to extract the contents of the file which you downloaded.
tar -xjf platform-tools-osx-aarch64.tar.bz2

Once extracted, move the contents to a convenient location, such as /usr/local/share.
sudo mv platform-tools/* /usr/local/share/platform-tools/

If this directory is not existed, then you can create it with below command.
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/platform-tools

Add platform Tools tool Path
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/platform-tools"' >> ~/.zshrc

source ~/.zshrc

After do it, verify installation
adb version


I tried to locate the wrong link and change it with the correct one, it didnt work... I downloaded it, extracted it, tried to use environment variable, nope... still wants to fetch the file from the wrong f.cking link! Thanks Solana! very good start for developing smart contracts....

how did you menage to change the link? i cant find the wrong link

It seems that that link is incorrect.
You can use this link and it is working well.
https://github.com/anza-xyz/platform-tools/releases/download/v1.42/move-dev-osx-aarch64.tar.bz2


I downloaded the folder separetely. Where should i put the folder so that build is successful
